# Leveraging ARR with WFF 2.0 and NTLM

Tags: web-farm-framework

I have successfully deployed the Web Farm Framework 2.0 module with a controller and two bound WFE servers.  I am able to use Application Provisioning, Load Balance, and the Routing Rules without much distress.  However, once I attempt to use Windows Authentication on the WFE (anonymous on the Controller), I am receiving a 401 error.  I am able to access the web applications directly via machine name, but that is against the point of using WFF right?  I am also able to access the site via cname (pointed at controller) if I have anonymous authentication enabled and All Users with Allow rights under .Net Authorization Rules.

I enabled Failed Request Tracing, but no log files were generated....so not sure where to go next.

Comment: Did you install CF10 on each server via the installer or did you push it out via a work flow?